# Скопировать object из List<object> в этот же лист , изменив один элемент

Tags: c#

Добрый вечер!

```
            humans = new List<Human>
        {
                new Human{ Name="Имя", Sex = Sex.Male ,Item = Item.Здоровый},
                new Human{ Name="Имя", Sex = Sex.Female ,Item = Item.Больной}
        };
```

Нужно всех здоровых людей из humans, скопировать (Добавить) в этот же list изменив их на больных ?

Что то в этом роде, но без temp Листа

```
list<Human> temp = new List<Human>;

temp = humans.Select(x => x.Item == Item.Здоровый ? new Human 
{ Name = x.Name, Sex = x.Sex, Item == Item.Больной}:x).ToList();

humans.AddRange(temp);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var humans = new List<Human>
    {
            new Human{ Name="Имя1", Sex = Sex.Male ,Item = Item.Здоровый},
            new Human{ Name="Имя2", Sex = Sex.Female ,Item = Item.Больной}
    };

humans.AddRange(humans
        .Where(h => h.Item == Item.Здоровый)
        .Select(h => new Human {Name=h.Name, Sex=h.Sex, Item = Item.Больной})
        .ToArray());

humans.ForEach(h => Console.WriteLine($"{h.Name} {h.Sex} {h.Item}"));
```

Вывод

```
Имя1 Male Здоровый
Имя2 Female Больной
Имя1 Male Больной
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно действительно без создания промежуточной коллекции, то предлагаю такой вариант:

```
int count = humans.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var h = humans[i];

    if (h.Item == Item.Здоровый)
        humans.Add(new Human { Name = h.Name, Sex = h.Sex, Item = Item.Больной });
}
```

Запоминаем текущее количество элементов в переменную `count`. И в цикле идём до этого значения. Изменённые элементы добавляются сразу в эту же коллекцию.

---

Впрочем, и в этом варианте может быть полное копирование коллекции *внутри*, если будет превышен объём `Capacity`.